# How long does the German naturalization process take?

Tags: germany, citizenship, passport

I hear cases like Greece and Italy, that it takes even years for the passport to get issued, after one applies for it.

Assuming one has fulfilled all the [requirements](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/themen/migration/staatsang/Erwerb_der_deutschen_Staatsbuergerschaft_durch_Eingbuergerung_en.html#doc9400756bodyText1) to obtain a German citizenship, how long does it take for the passport to get issued?

Wikipedia says it takes [four to six weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_passport#Time_of_processing) to process, but does it really take that long?

Comment: How is this about expatriation?

Comment: @fkraiem It's literally on the bullet points on the [on topic](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page

Comment: I do not see anything about passport applications there. If you are, for example, a German citizen living outside Germany and applying for a German passport from there, then you should state so in the question (and say where you are applying from)

Comment: @fkraiem 
"Questions about permanent residence and nationality programs, as they would apply to someone of your nationality living in, or planning to move to a foreign country"

Comment: @Snow I understand "nationality programs" to refer to naturalization and other means of acquiring a country's nationality, not to administrative details such as passport issue.  Your question is probably on topic at [Travel.SE], but unless you live outside of Germany and say so in the question, it's not on topic here.  (Also, the "years" to get the passport in other countries, as far as I've heard of it, refers to the administrative evaluation of the applicant's citizenship, that is, deciding whether they are in fact entitled; I don't think it applies to renewals or simple first applications.)

Comment: @phoog I am talking about naturalization in the question. I'm an expat living in Germany, who wants to acquire a German passport

Comment: In other words you want to apply for German **Nationality**? If so, you should reword your question. Or better still, ask  a new question with the correct terminology.

Comment: Applying for naturalization is not at all the same as applying for a passport.  Having a country's nationality is a prerequisite for a successful passport application.  The four-to-six week processing time is the time for a German citizen to get a new passport.  You can expect your passport application to take that long after you are naturalized.  As noted by @MarkJohnson, the question of processing time for naturalization is entirely separate.  In other words, "assuming one has passed all the requirements to obtain a German passport" is tantamount to assuming that one is already naturalized.

Comment: @MarkJohnson edited the title

Comment: @phoog by requirements I mean [these](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/themen/migration/staatsang/Erwerb_der_deutschen_Staatsbuergerschaft_durch_Eingbuergerung_en.html#doc9400756bodyText1)

Comment: @phoog I assumed you'd take it for granted that when applying for a nationality, you are inadvertently applying for the passport. They go hand in hand

Comment: @Snow That is a incorrect assumption and only leads  to misunderstandings since they are 2 different processes.

Comment: @phoog The source I linked says how long does it take for you to be eligible to apply for the citizenship. It doesn't say how long does it take for you to actually acquire it after you apply.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I see that my assumption was wrong, sorry for the confusion. I hope it's clear now

Comment: @Snow I have adapted the answer as far as in a general answer can be done. This includes some aspects that are never mentioned in the official sites and caused 'surprise'  to those who have gone through the process.

Comment: @snow I was talking about the "four to six weeks" link, not the "requirements" link.  The four to six weeks link is about administrative passport processing for German citizens, not about naturalization applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long the [Nationalzation](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/318998/) process takes, varies greatly depending on your personal situation.

In general 6 months can be assumed, after which a [**Einbürgerungszusicherung**](https://www.hamburg.de/innenbehoerde/verfahrensablauf/) (assurance of naturalization)  will be issued.

In most cases you are then required to relinquish your previous citizenship, which **must be completed** before the Nationalzation takes place.

**Note**: Country's that do not allow their citizens to relinquish their citizenship or cause severe disadvantages are known and exceptions are made in these cases.

Otherwise for other countries this process can be very simple, others very time consuming and/or expensive

- the [**United States**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relinquishment_of_United_States_nationality) belongs to the latter catagory

Assume that you may be **Stateless**, since some countries revoke it immediately but confirm it only after it goes through their due process.

Should the process take longer than 6 months, assume that the conditions for Nationalzation will be **rechecked**, which again can take a few months.

After some form of [**Loss of Nationality** Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_citizenship)  has been issued, a **Einbürgerungsurkunde** will be handed out.

---

After the Nationalzation process has ended (you have received a **Einbürgerungsurkunde**), you must bring the **original** togeather with a **certified translated version of your birth certificate** to the **Meldebehörde** (Registration Office). You should also take some (3-5) photocopies of the **Einbürgerungsurkunde** with you.

There the change of citizenship will then be ammended to your record. Any photocopies will then be certified.

You may be required to do the same with the **Standesamt** depending on which state you live in.

After this the original **Einbürgerungsurkunde** (and the birth certificate) should not be asked for again, since a certified copy should be sufficient.

Otherwise a certified copy of the **Einbürgerungsurkunde** should be given to any **official** authorities that know you as a foreigner

- Ausländerbehörde, Job Center (Work Permit) and your present employer

so that they can 'close' their record of you as a foreigner.

For anyone else, the Identity card should be sufficient.

---

Once the **Meldebehörde** has changed your record, you can apply for an Identity Card and/or Passport.

> Wikipedia says it takes four to six weeks to process, but does it really take that long?

Yes, since they are, just as driver's licenses, printed in the Bundesdruckerei.

See [another answer for more details](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19663/17166).

---

**Sources**:

- [germany - Waiting time to receive German license](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19663/17166)
- [Einbürgerung - Dienstleistungen - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/318998/) (in German)

  - [Verfahrensablauf - hamburg.de](https://www.hamburg.de/innenbehoerde/verfahrensablauf/) (in German)
- [Loss of citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_citizenship)
- [Relinquishment of United States nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relinquishment_of_United_States_nationality)

  - [Certificate of Loss of Nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_Loss_of_Nationality)
  - [Expatriation tax](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expatriation_tax#United_States)

Comment: There should be much more exceptions from the rule of cancelling the previous citizenship, rather than just " Country's that do not allow their citizens to relinquish their citizenship". For example, old people, political refugees, etc. Also, one is allowed to retain his/her previous citizenship if losing it will lead to high economical or financial losses for him/her and so on.

Comment: @AndreySapegin The question is about how long the process takes, **not** about all the rules and exceptions in detail.

Answer (score 0):

**It depends** on a case-by-case basis.

[Source 1](https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/visa/living-permanently-in-germany/naturalisation/process/):

> How long it takes all in all from the time you apply to the presentation of the certificate varies from case to case. In many cases it can take several months. The best thing is to talk with your local naturalisation authority.

[Source 2](https://mkenyaujerumani.de/2017/02/09/how-long-does-the-naturalization-einburgerung-process-take/):

> Normal Process: 6 months – 27 months

[Source 3](https://www.iamexpat.de/expat-info/official-issues/german-citizenship-deutsche-staatsangehoerigkeit):

> Once your application has been considered, the citizenship authority will send you the outcome via post. This can take anywhere between a few weeks and several months.

[Source 4](https://transferwise.com/gb/blog/how-to-get-citizenship-in-germany):

> The processing time for your citizenship application depends on your personal circumstances and the workload of your local naturalisation authority. Your local office will be able to give you an idea of processing time when you submit your application or at your advice session if you have one.

All in all, hope for your local Einbürgerungsamt to be in a good mood and not too busy.